# Laravel 7.5.2 (Passport Api) + Ajax Error : Undefined index: aud , \\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Guards\\TokenGuard.php

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 7.5.2 with Vuejs. I am using passport for api authentication.
I have followed passport installation instruction on laravel website.

- Has run composer require laravel/passport, php artisan migrate and php artisan passport:install
- Has added HasApiTokens in user model
- Has added Passport::routes() in AuthServiceProvider
- Has added \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class in App\Http\Kernel web middlewareGroups
- Has changed Api driver to passport in config/auth.php

The cookie named "laravel_token" is getting generated and sent with ajax request as I can see in developer tool.

In my controller I have included api middleware as

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Api/Ajax Response

```
{
"message": "Undefined index: aud",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "E:\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Guards\\TokenGuard.php",
"line": 140,
"trace": [
    {
...
}
]
```

I have also tried: composer dump-autoload

My Setup

- Laravel: 7.5.2
- Passport: 9.0
- PHP : 7.4.0
- Vuejs: 2.5.17

The issue is not only related to vuejs. It's related to ajax requests from simple javascript or could be from any framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some problem in laravel/passport version 9.0. Upgrading to version 9.0.1 fixed the issue.

```
composer update laravel/passport:9.0.1
```

The details of the issue can be found here:
[Issue Detail on Github](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1243)

Thanks to those who fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `php artisan passport:install`?

It's needed to install keys in your storage directory.

Comment: yes, I have run  php artisan migrate and  php artisan passport:install