# Laravel7 Passport: Getting "Undefined index: aud" when trying to send the request to "api/user"

Tags: php, vuejs2, passport.js, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 & Vue 2 along with the Passport. I'm trying to hit the api/user endpoint but getting this error.

NOTE: I've gone through all the passport implementation process mentioned in https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport . but still getting this error.

**api call in my Vue Component:**

```
created() {
   axios.get("/api/user")
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

The error:
[image]

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: The issue is fixed laravel passport version 9.0.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61650784/4257737

Answer (score 1):

The server code is expecting an ["aud" ("audience") token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418360/jwt-json-web-token-audience-aud-versus-client-id-whats-the-difference) which is not supplied:

OIDC has ID Tokens in addition to Access tokens. The OIDC spec is explicit on the use of the aud claim in ID Tokens. (openid-connect-core-1.0)

> **aud**
>
> **REQUIRED**. Audience(s) that this ID Token is intended for. It MUST contain the OAuth 2.0 `client_id` of the Relying Party as an audience
>   value. It MAY also contain identifiers for other audiences. In the
>   general case, the aud value is an array of case sensitive strings. In
>   the common special case when there is one audience, the aud value MAY
>   be a single case sensitive string.

Additionally, there is no `array_key_exists()` check in the code to gracefully handle the missing token case.

The answer above suggests some workarounds if you cannot supply the required information.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, it's relaated to last version of Passport (v9). Try to use version 8.5 to be sure and check and have a look here https://github.com/laravel/passport

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to passport version 9.0.1 solved the issue.